# UIActivityViewController: prevent activity from appearing if an error occurs after the user selects the activity?

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, ios-sharesheet

In my app, I have a `UIActivityViewController` containing standard items like `UIMailActivity` (and Messages, Facebook, etc). Sometimes, the user will tap one of these activities, but an error will occur that prevents sharing of the item. What ends up happening is an error message will be displayed, but Mail (or Messages etc) will open up anyway with no content.

Is there a way to either:

- Prevent the activity from running if an error occurs
- Immediately dismiss the activity if an error occurs

Comment: Have you set `controller.excludedActivityTypes` to exclude the ones you don't need to prevent the error? You can  `activityViewController.setCompletionHandler` to control the result

Comment: To clarify, at the time the `UIActivityViewController` is presented, the Mail, Messages, etc activities should be available. After the user taps the item, an error (that I don't know about in advance) may occur, and at that time I would like to prevent the UI from being displayed.